# Compose a query to get a complete record against max

Tags: elixir, ecto

In `Ecto.Query.Api` we use `max` in the `select` to get the max value in a field like this:

```
from q in jobs,
select: max(q.cost)
```

It will return the `max` value in the field.

If i want to return the complete record against that max value. I have to use `where` not `select`.

So how can i use `max` in where?

So In my understanding I think i have to use `fragment` in the `where`.

So what is the best possible solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While one might construct a fragment using an overcomplicated `where` clause, the real task is really to get a topmost record when the table is  ordered by `cost`:

```
from q in jobs,
order_by: [desc: q.cost],
limit: 1
```